# Executing SQL statement stored as a field value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to execute a SQL statement that has been stored within a table as text.

I am trying to create a configuration table to drive a large number of SSRS subscriptions and don’t want to code any values directly into the report I want them all driven from a table for maintance.

E.G.

If part of one reports file name will always be the year of the previous month (2013 for example) but this needs to be generated at run time.

Can I stored this as a text field

```
CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Then execute it and resolve the result into a SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then yes by using dynamic SQL. For example:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(4)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @yr = CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@yr VARCHAR(4) OUTPUT', @yr=@YEAR OUTPUT

SELECT @YEAR
```

...returns 2013 into variable @YEAR.

Here I've hardcoded the query but it is a simple case to build the value of @SQL from a table's column value instead. You can then use the result from this query to build another dynamic query and so on.

Below is a subset of the above showing the SQL being taken from a table instead:

```
CREATE TABLE Dynamic (id INTEGER, text VARCHAR(4000) )
INSERT Dynamic values (1, 'CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))')

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @yr = ' + (SELECT text FROM Dynamic WHERE id =  1)
```

Comment: Sorry really struggling to get the correct syntax to build the @Sql from a tables column value. Can you help?

Comment: @DavidA please see my edit. Hopefully it's as straightforward as that?

Comment: 99% is there a way of passing a parameter to specify the ID value?

Comment: You can use a variable, e.g. DECLARE &id INT, SET &id = 1, ...WHERE id = &id). You could get the value for that variable from another table or accept it as an input parameter if this is a Stored Procedure? (note I've used '&' instead of the correct 'at' symbol above because the 'at' symbol has a special meaning in comments).

Comment: Phew finally got there. A combination of missing brackets and looking too hard at it for too long! Got there in the end. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

why couldn't you?

Is it only one line of values per report?

I see 2 choices with SSRS.

1) everything in sql, you do dynamic sql.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000) 
select @sql = 'select * from mytable where year = ' mavar'
from tablevalue  where uniqueid = blablabla
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

second possibilty :

You make a first dataset in SSRS getting this value and then you evaluate the value of your condition and send it to a third dataset.

If you have multiple values, you can still imagine to get the value from a first dataset, evaluate them and send this to a subreport.

I don't know your application enought to determine the performance of this.

Until you are in SSRS, i recommand to try to find a solution in SSRS instead of Sql (but it's not a gold rule at all!!!)